# Create an average table excluding some values

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table with this structure:

| Date | DeviceID | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2022 | SensorA | 1200 |
| 01/01/2022 | SensorB | 1300 |
| 01/01/2022 | SensorC | 900 |
| 02/01/2022 | SensorA | 500 |
| 02/01/2022 | SensorB | 50 |
| 02/01/2022 | SensorC | 39 |

I'm interesting in create a new table that have the average by day of all sensors values but excluding the values which are lower than the average of all sensors by day.
For example for 01/01/2022 the average of all sensors values is:

`(1200+1300+900) / 3 = 1133.3`

We then calculate the average sensor value for the day, excluding `SensorC` because its value is below `1133.3`:

`(1200+1300) / 2 = 1250`

The final table have to looks like this:

| Date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 01/01/2022 | 1250 |
| 02/01/2022 | 500 |

Is it possible? Hope you can help me

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does exactly what you are asking for:

```
Avg Excl = 
VAR _avg = AVERAGE ( 'Table'[Value] )
RETURN
CALCULATE ( 
    AVERAGE ( 'Table'[Value] ) , 
    'Table'[Value] > _avg 
)
```

Result:
[image]

If you want to persist a DAX table to your model, you just use this code together with `SUMMARIZE`:

```
New_Table = 
SUMMARIZE ( 
    'Table' , 
    'Table'[Date] , 
    "Value",
    VAR _avg = AVERAGE ( 'Table'[Value] )
    RETURN
    CALCULATE ( 
        AVERAGE ( 'Table'[Value] ) , 
        'Table'[Value] > _avg 
    )
)
```

Result:

[image]

For good measure, here is some Power Query code to achieve the same result. Usually this is best practice due to compression efficiency and such in Power BI. As a bonus, it also makes working with the `pbix` file smoother since you don't have to wait for the table to recalculate all the time when you add/remove/edit DAX components.

This solution is your best bet if this his how you actually want your table to look, since you can get rid of the original table in the model altogether and not have it in the model as a dependency. You can paste this into a blank query:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRecords({
        [Date="2022-01-01", DeviceID="SensorA",Value=1200],
        [Date="2022-01-01", DeviceID="SensorB",Value=1300],
        [Date="2022-01-01", DeviceID="SensorC",Value=900],
        [Date="2022-01-02", DeviceID="SensorA",Value=500],
        [Date="2022-01-02", DeviceID="SensorB",Value=50],
        [Date="2022-01-02", DeviceID="SensorC",Value=39]
    }),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Date", type date}, 
        {"DeviceID", type text}, 
        {"Value", Int64.Type}
    }),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Date"}, {
        {"Avg", each List.Average([Value]), type nullable number}, 
        {"Data", each _, type table [Date=nullable date, DeviceID=nullable text, Value=nullable number]}
    }),
    #"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Data", {"Value"}, {"Data.Value"}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Data", "Custom", each if [Data.Value] > [Avg] then [Data.Value] else null),
    #"Grouped Rows1" = Table.Group(#"Added Custom", {"Date"}, {{"Avg Value", each List.Average([Custom]), type nullable number}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows1"
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need a table with this not a measure to make relationships. Any idea?

Comment: Weird requirement - but I have added code on how to make this into a DAX table.

Comment: Thanks man, it works as I wanted! Have a nice day!

Comment: Glad to hear! Please remember to accept the answer for posterity :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the Device ID column in the table, it shows all of them separately. Can you remove the DeviceID column and try the value column as average?